# Run an Angular directive after DOM has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I've recently started using Angular. I want to run a directive after my DOM loads. How exactly would I do this?

To what element on the page should I attach the following directive? My initial thought was the closing body tag, but as I am using an Angular template, I'm not sure how to access the body tags.

```
.directive('on_page_load', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function($scope, $elem, attrs){
          $(window).load(function() {
               console.log('loaded')
          })
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: You should be able to add it to any of them. My opinion would be the opening body tag.

Comment: I don't quite get the planned purpose of this directive...

Comment: I want to do something to the page after it loads.

Comment: I don't think directive is a good place to listen to `$window.load`

Comment: I see, would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I would keep listener in a service or in a controller, and the rest depends on what you want to do with the page... if it is DOM manipulation, what kind of manipulation...

Comment: Well I had the directive in a service, which was being called by my controller. So I thought I was on the right track. I basically want to check whether or not a particular element exists after the DOM loads. I can do it in a second with jQuery, but it's taking me much longer with Angular.

Comment: from my POV, it has no sense to create a directive just for this check... in this case I would probably leave it in a controller completely

Answer (score 0):

A directive is the wrong tool to do it.
You should use the "run" method for that purpose.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

See:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-bootstrap-app-init